# How to resolve LocationException of ProximityListener in j2me

Tags: java-me, jsr179

My code for addProximityListener is -

```
Coordinates proxcoord = new Coordinates(0.0, 0.0, 0.0f); 
proxcoord.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
proxcoord.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lon));
provider.addProximityListener(this, proxcoord, 40.0f);
```

While adding ProximityListener to location provider platform showing me an error which are as follows -

```
javax.microedition.location.LocationException
at javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider.addProximityListener(+7)
at mobilelocationreminder.MobileLocationReminder.commandAction(+4414)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable.callKeyPressed(+269)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Form.callKeyPressed(+243)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.consumeUIEvent(+101)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayAccessor.consumeEvent(+117)
null
```

I saw its error meaning in documentation which is
LocationException - if the platform does not have resources to add a new listener and coordinates to be monitored or does not support proximity monitoring at all

But i am not getting how to solve this problem???